# Symfony sfPHPExcelPlugin in Linux

Tags: php, symfony1

I'm using the PHPExcel plugin for Symfony 1.4 (sfPHPExcelPlugin) on Ubuntu (using PHP 5.10), with this code for saving the file that I am writing:

```
// Save Excel 2007 file
echo date('H:i:s') . " Write to Excel2007 format\n";
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));

// Echo done
echo date('H:i:s') . " Done writing file.\r\n";
```

I am sure that the execution is reaching this part of the code, because the echo messages are shown but I am not downloading the Excel file! Could it be because I am trying it in Linux, not in Windows?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in this code that results in you downloading the file. It simply saves it to the disk.

Comment: Thanks! It was exactly that, the save() did save but in the /lib/model folder.... :-/